# How to draw this circle if we can't use the graphics classes in java (jdk)?

Tags: java, eclipse

We need to write a program where the user specifies the radius using the scanner method and then the output should make a circle using stars "*" whose radius equals to that of the user input. We have to use the (While) command (and maybe substrings?), however we haven't taken yet the graphics classes

Comment: [System.]out.print(...)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "graphics classes" to do this problem, simply print out the *'s in the console in the shape of a circle. So for example, a circle with a radius of 2 would be

```
 **
*  *
 **
```

Depending on if you are including the last * as a space or not.

An algorithm needs to be written to take in the input, multiply it by 2 to get the diameter, then print it out in the correct format.

To print it out simply use

```
System.out.println("*");
```

Comment: i tried to do the same ended up getting a diamond instead of a circle for big radiuses ...

Comment: Well then something is wrong with your algorithm, but that isn't your question that you posted.

Comment: what should be the algorithm then?